# Generating push notifications after installing firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated `Firebase` into my project and I think I have followed all the steps required for generating push notifications within the app. I have also tested the push notifications by sending some dummy notifications from the Firebase console.

[This](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/) is the tutorial I entirely followed.

Now my questions are..

1. How will I get the `FCM ID` so that I can send it in my api call.
2. When a push notification comes, where do I handle it..?
3. Where do I mention things like when to receive the notifications and the actions to take while tapping on notifications..?

**EDIT 1**

So this is all the code I have for handling push notifications...

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`...

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()
```

And then,

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
    print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]){
    print("userInfo:->  \(userInfo)")

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Q1   :- First Method 
>       Q2&3 :- Second Method

```
     func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
                let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
                print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
         }

         func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]){
         print("userInfo:->  \(userInfo)")
        }

     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

            print("userInfo:->  \(userInfo)")
            let redirect_flag = userInfo["redirect_flag"]as! String

            if application.applicationState == .inactive {
              // handle when you background 
         }
    }else{
          // Here You need to handle all terms which you handle in 
             didReceiveRemoteNotification  method
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I have for push notifications. Is this all that is required..? Will I get all details of a push notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`..?

Comment: @v.bw yes you get all detail on that method

Comment: @v.bw not mention

Comment: Just one more concern @Tm Goyani...Hope you don't mind..:) In which methods can I handle the notifications when app is in foreground and background..?

Comment: @v.bw  that both method required if you want to go with IOS 10 above and belove both

Comment: ok @ Tm Goyani..so you mean the `else` case will handle when I'm in foreground..?

Comment: @v.bw yes, but you want to go with both method   Coz iOS handle

Comment: wish u the same @ Tm Goyani...:)