# Experimenting with Firebase - Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to try out Push Notifications with Firebase I am following this example:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/dc2cd2db6e82e5c475fa3f0efe75df8b54f04544/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55

I could make it work up to a certain point.

Here is the relevant code I have:

```
......

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    ......
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    ......

    return true
}

......

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print(#function)
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}

......
```

When I try to test it, the function *userNotificationCenter:didReceive:withCompletionHandler()* is the only one called (in the list of function provided by the example). It should also be noticed that I can see this looking at the debugger console and nothing is happening on the device. I guess that's the way it's supposed to be (so all is fine), but here is a question I have for anyone who can answer.

How do I make use of *completionHandler()* ?
I suppose, since it's a parameter I can make some use of it in a rather free way, but when I look for sample code on the net I can only see it declared in the list of parameters or called as is the case in the example I am working with, but I never see it defined.

Is there something I should look at or a concrete example of how to make use of it?

For information, I am using Xcode Version 10.1, iOS 12.1  and Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter), `completionHandler` in this method is:

> The block to execute when you have finished processing the user’s
>   response. You must execute this block at some point after processing
>   the user's response to let the system know that you are done. The
>   block has no return value or parameters.

So you should call completion handler when you are done processing the notification. You cannot use it in any other way. Once you call it, the system then knows you are done with the notification and can perform any needed processes, such as putting the notification in the user's notification center.

Comment: Indeed I also had read this part of the documentation. What I would like to have though is a concrete example, where this completion handler parameter is used in one way and another concrete example, where the completion handler parameter is used in another way. Even if the place where it should be called is decided, since it's a parameter I suppose I must have some kind of control on it.

Comment: Another way to ask the same question is: Could the line of code "withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {" be written a different way, in order to get a slightly different result?

Comment: That's the point! You cannot use this method's completion handler in any other way. you just need to call it at the end of the method. else, you will probably face unwanted behavior. No other usage. 
Check this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter
In this case, you can call its completion with custom parameters to specify how you want the system to alert the user, and if you don't call it, no alert will be used. But in the method you mentioned, it's just a callback that has no parameters and returns void.

Comment: The documentation says "The block to execute with the presentation option for the notification......". In my case there is no block, so I should be able to put a block of code. How to do this is my current problem.

Comment: I was just able to have a notification fire on my device. Even though all is not yet cristal clear, it is starting to make sense.

Comment: You cant put code in the block, you just call it here, the block is implemented on the other side that is waiting for the callback response which you call here.

Comment: OK. Then I suppose this other side that you are referring to is what I want to know about.

Comment: That is implemented in iOS SDK I suppose.

Comment: With no control possible for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184374/discussion-between-mrfrhn-and-michel).

Comment: A more down to earth question: if I want to do something useful when my app receives a notification from the cloud (I mean other than a beep or a pop up window), where am I supposed to implement that functionality? Before calling this completionHandler we were talking about earlier? (I had first thought it would be inside ... but since it appears to be untouchable I have to do it somewhere else.)

Comment: I thought we were in chat??